# Stop tracking "ServiceBusProcessor.ProcessMessage" activity in Application Insights

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, appinsights

**Hello**

I need to stop tracking this activity in AI

[image: AI logs]

As I understood from AI documentation - it's log about successfully processed message from Azure service bus.

This log records has no value for me

Thank  for help!

Comment: Can you share more context about how you're capturing logs and pushing them to AI?   Is your application an Azure Function, an ASP.NET Core application, or stand-alone?

Comment: ASP.NET Core application

Answer (score 2):

In an ASP.NET application, the ETW logs emitted by the Service Bus client library are forwarded to `ILogger` based on the active log level configuration.  If you'd like to tune Service Bus to something different than the global value, you can set a specific level as part of logging configuration.

For example, the following sets the Service Bus logs to be captured only for warnings and errors while the other Azure SDK logs are set for error only:

```json
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "System": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Azure.Core": "Error",
    "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus": "Warning"
  }
}
```

More information on how the Azure SDK logging configuration maps to the Functions logging can be found in the article [Logging with the Azure SDK for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/azure/sdk/logging#map-to-aspnet-core-logging).